# Hazelcast Count mechanism

Tags: java, hashmap, hazelcast

I was trying to use hazelcast aggregation to perform the count operations.

Example:-

Here I'm looking to count number of salary1 fields present in the json.

```
String json1 = "{\r\n" + "    \"salary\": 200\r\n" + "}";
String json2 = "{\r\n" + "    \"salary\": 300\r\n" + "}";
String json5 = "{\r\n" + "  \"salary1\": 300\r\n" + "}";

map.put(1, new HazelcastJsonValue(json1));
map.put(2, new HazelcastJsonValue(json2));
map.put(3, new HazelcastJsonValue(json5));
Long count = map.aggregate(Aggregators.count("salary1"));
System.out.println("count is " + count);
```

I have only one salary1 field but its still giving the full count.

what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `Predicate` to filter first the entries you count. Try the following.

```
Predicate p = Predicates.notEqual("salary1", null);
Long count = map.aggregate(Aggregators.count(), p);
```